# Struts2 Autocompleter - Entry lost when submit-button is clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, struts2, autocomplete

I use:

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/autocompleter.html

and the problem is:

When typing:

"Ball"

Autocomplete finds "Balloon"

and in the textfield I see "Balloon" and in the list below also "Balloon". When I click anywhere else on the monitor it displays "Balloon" in the textfield. But when I click submit, I reads "Ball" from the textfield. Why? And how?

Greetings,
Rhodarus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not use Struts Ajax tags anymore, [because](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ajax-tags.html):

> **Dojo plugin is deprecated**
>
> The Dojo plugin will be deprecated on Struts 2.1

If you are starting now, you can use [raw Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) (today at `1.10` version, instead of the old, buggy `0.4.x` version shipped with Struts2; but it would probably be easier to migrate to jQuery, especially iwth the help of [Struts2-jQuery-plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action).

You can see the example of its Autocompleter under the <kbd>Widgets</kbd> menu.

BTW, if for some reason you want to stick with the old integrated Dojo version (for example while working on a huge and legacy project only for a minimal correction), ensure you are using it correctly: return a valid Json object, publish and subscribe the right topics, etc. as shown in the example from [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-plugins/struts2-dojo-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dojo/components/Autocompleter.html):

```
 <sx:autocompleter name="autocompleter1" href="%{jsonList}"/>



 <s:autocompleter name="test"  list="{'apple','banana','grape','pear'}" autoComplete="false"/>

 <sx:autocompleter name="mvc" href="%{jsonList}" loadOnTextChange="true" loadMinimumCount="3"/>
```

> The text entered on the autocompleter is passed as a parameter to the url specified in "href", like (text is "struts"): `http://host/example/myaction.do?mvc=struts`

```
<form id="selectForm">
      <sx:autocompleter  name="select" list="{'fruits','colors'}"  valueNotifyTopics="/changed" />
 </form>  
 <sx:autocompleter  href="%{jsonList}" formId="selectForm" listenTopics="/changed"/>



 <sx:autocompleter  href="%{jsonList}" id="auto"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function getValues() {
      var autoCompleter = dojo.widget.byId("auto");

      //key (in the states example above, "AL")
      var key = autoCompleter.getSelectedKey();
      alert(key);

      //value (in the states example above, "Alabama")
      var value = autoCompleter.getSelectedValue();
      alert(value);

      //text currently on the textbox (anything the user typed)
      var text = autoCompleter.getText();
      alert(text);
   }

   function setValues() {
      var autoCompleter = dojo.widget.byId("auto");

      //key (key will be set to "AL" and value to "Alabama")
      autoCompleter.setSelectedKey("AL");

      //value (key will be set to "AL" and value to "Alabama")
      autoCompleter.setAllValues("AL", "Alabama");
   }
 </script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/before", function(event, widget){
     alert('inside a topic event. before request');
     //event: set event.cancel = true, to cancel request
     //widget: widget that published the topic
 });
 </script>         

 <sx:autocompleter beforeNotifyTopics="/before" href="%{#ajaxTest} />



 <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/after", function(data, request, widget){
     alert('inside a topic event. after request');
     //data : JavaScript object from parsing response
     //request: XMLHttpRequest object
     //widget: widget that published the topic
 });
 </script>        

 <sx:autocompleter afterNotifyTopics="/after" href="%{#ajaxTest}" />



 <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/error", function(error, request, widget){
     alert('inside a topic event. on error');
     //error : error object (error.message has the error message)
     //request: XMLHttpRequest object
     //widget: widget that published the topic
 });
 </script>

 <sx:autocompleter errorNotifyTopics="/error" href="%{#ajaxTest}" />



 <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.event.topic.subscribe("/value", function(value, key, text, widget){
     alert('inside a topic event. after value changed');
     //value : selected value (like "Florida" in example above)
     //key: selected key (like "FL" in example above)
     //text: text typed into textbox
     //widget: widget that published the topic
 });
 </script>   

 <sx:autocompleter valueNotifyTopics="/value" href="%{#ajaxTest}" />
```