# Events javascript enable with Struts 2

Tags: javascript, struts2, autocomplete, onchange

I'm new here, so as the tittle said, i have a problem when i try to use javascript events with struts 2, actually with the `onchange` event from javascript and this tag from Struts 2 "autocompleter", i try to call to the `getValues` function but this is not invoked when the autocompleter tag value change.

Struts 2 Tag

```
<s:url id="linkActionProveedoresList" action="proveedorJSONAction" /> 
<sx:autocompleter href="%{linkActionProveedoresList}" name="proveedorSelecionado"
                  id="proveedorSelecionado" onchange="getValues(this)" />

<script>
    function getValues(value) 
    {
        //business logic here!
        alert("invokation successful");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25990946/1654265